# ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01830

The SQL works fine on most installations.  However I'm having a problem with an Oracle installation in Canada (possible date localization issue?).

http://www.google.com/search?q=ORA-01830

I'm feeding data to a proprietary processor that generates the SQL.  I only provide data.  I was hoping for information that may help me solve it without involving support from the processor.

Comment: Why don't you provide some information, like what the query looks like and what sort of data is being fed to it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do not rely on implicit date conversions.

Code like:

```
MY_TABLE.MY_DATE_COLUMN >= '03/07/2008'
```

is bad practice. Use either:

```
MY_TABLE.MY_DATE_COLUMN >= to_date('03/07/2008','mm/dd/yyyy')
```

or

```
MY_TABLE.MY_DATE_COLUMN >= date '2008-03-07'
```