# date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Tags: java, oracle, date, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595072/ora-01830-date-format-picture-ends-before-converting-entire-input-string)

I am getting the system current date and time with the following:

```
String months[] = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr","May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug","Sep", "Oct",     "Nov", "Dec"};
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
String month = (months[cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)]);
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

int second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);

String date= day+"/"+month+"/"+year;
String time=hour+":"+minute+":"+second;

ps.setString(14, date+" "+time);
```

But, now when I try to insert the date and time in the table using prepared statement as above.

The following error comes:

> date format picture ends before converting entire input string

How can I solve this?

Comment: There's an Oracle tag. Is there SQL or PL/SQL code involved?

Comment: This isn't a Java problem, the Java code works fine.

Comment: Can you print the value of date variable? The error message clearly says that input string is larger than the provided date format. You need to make sure that your string should contain exactly 14 characters.

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21344930

Comment: This is an Oracle error and it means that the date you are trying to insert into a table does not match the date format of the table column.

Comment: I doubt `14` has anything to do with this, this is just an oracle format mismatch.

Comment: 14 character support the format like "dd-mm-yy hh:mm" but i think your date format like:-  "dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss" please check the exact format by print the value of date variable.

Comment: But there is no 14-character restriction; the `14` in the `setString` is the index for the positional parameter in the parsed SQL statement, and nothing to do with its length.   It's more likely that the default `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is expecting `DD/MM/YYYY` and it doesn't know what to do with the rest of the string, i.e. the time part. As @yatul suggests, the insert statement probably just needs to specify the format mask instead of rely on implicit conversion.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to pass to your PreparedStatement Date instead of String if your column has type for storing date and time
2. If you just want to save create or update timestamp it's easier and less error-prone to make this with DB using trigger or default column value
3. For formatting date to string it's better to use SimpleDateFormat or similar.
4. If you want to pass String to be parsed by Oracle you should care about locale settings in Oracle and your app, or you can modify your script to contains format: e.g. use somethig similar to `to_date(:paramString, 'YOUR_DATE_FORMAT')`